# How to filter a time series pandas dataframe based on two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

So I have a time series data frame which has both Patient Ids in one column and Years ( 1 - 3) in another columns. What I want to do using pandas is,  for each unique patient Id only keep rows that have entries for all the Years 1-3.

IN

```
ID  Year 
111  1 
111  2 
111  3 
222  1 
222  2
333  1
333  2
333  3
```

OUT

```
ID  Year 
111  1 
111  2 
111  3 
333  1
333  2
333  3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in one line like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": [111, 111, 111, 222, 222, 333, 333, 333],
    "Year": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]})

# filter unique IDs that doesn't contain [1, 2, 3]
df = df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda g: (sorted(set(g["Year"].values)) == [1,2,3]))
print(df)
#    ID  Year
#0  111     1
#1  111     2
#2  111     3
#5  333     1
#6  333     2
#7  333     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that *Year* can be only *1* thru *3*, you can run:

```
result = df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda grp: grp.Year.unique().size == 3)
```

`unique()` is needed to filter out cases when there are e.g. 3 rows for
particular *ID*, but all from the same *Year*.